# DIVs and CSS layout not lining up, but why?

Tags: css

I'm trying to layout a screen using `div`'s and CSS. It's a simple layout at this point but I can't seem to get the `div`'s to line up. I want one wrapper `div` with two `div`'s within it: one aligned to the left and one aligned to the right. However, they end up on top of each other.

I know this question is simple. What am I missing here?

If I reduce the width of the right `div` to `60%` it lines up right but shouldn't I be able to use `100%` of the width of the parent `div`?

```css
#product_wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 75%;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: top;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#images_wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#content_wrapper {
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="product_wrapper">
  <div id="images_wrapper">Foo</div>
  <div id="content_wrapper">Bar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: look up float or absolute positioning

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: @flasshy the issue is the whitespace caused by inline-block so, have a look: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: I apologize, Oriol. I'll look at that thread, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Float left your children elements:

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/vufutu/2/edit)***

```
#product_wrapper > *{float:left;}
```

Note that `inline-block` causes the inner elements to actually act like `inline` elements
**where white spaces count!**

---

SO **another way** would be to modify your HTML removing the *NewLine* separator:

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/vufutu/1/edit)***

```
<div id="images_wrapper">

     Foo content

</div><div id="content_wrapper">
     ^^-------------------------------------- no space here

     Bar content

</div>
```

The third way (the **worst** one) is to set **font-size to 0** for the parent (will remove logically the child's white-space gap since is now '0'); >> and than reset the font-size for children elements to `px` (cause `em` will not work since parent has `0`).
But that's a good way to loose track of dynamic and responsive font sizes expecially if you use `em` and size inheritances.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware that white spaces count in this case.

If I use float:left and float:right, I'd have to make those DIV's display:inline then can't set height and width.

Sorry if this question is dumb. I'm still learning layouts with DIV's.

Comment: @flasshy No you *don't need*  to make them inline. Why would you?

Comment: Because...I'm still getting a full grasp on layouts with DIV's? Haha I thought I knew but I'm not 100% there. I thought float was just another attribute to use in addition to display.

Comment: @flasshy I really don't understand your comments. Added TWO demo links in my answer for you (since you're lazy ;) ) to preview what I tried to explain :) Happy coding!

Comment: I'm not lazy. I've been playing with code and searching on the web. I've been trying. Only now did I resort to asking here. All I said was that I thought display and float worked in unison. I now know they do not and I thank you for that clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the whitespace in the html, which occupies some space between the elements.

One way of fixing it is

```css
#product_wrapper {
  font-size: 0;    /* Hide whitespace in the html */
}
#images_wrapper, #content_wrapper {
  font-size: 16px; /* Reset to whatever vaue */
}
```

```css
#product_wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 75%;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: top;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 0;
}
#images_wrapper, #content_wrapper {
  font-size: 16px;
}
#images_wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#content_wrapper {
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="product_wrapper">
  <div id="images_wrapper">Foo</div>
  <div id="content_wrapper">Bar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does that mean my fonts within those DIV's will have to use that font-size?

Comment: @flasshy It can be any value. But the problem is that it can't be inherited from the grandparent.

Comment: Hmm. When I set it to font-size: 10pt, it goes back to the broken state.

Comment: I see, @Oriol. You keep the wrapper DIV's with the font-size: 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use float:left instead of display:inline-block

```css
#product_wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 75%;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: top;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#images_wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  float:left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#content_wrapper {
  background-color: blue;
  float:left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="product_wrapper">
  <div id="images_wrapper">Foo</div>
  <div id="content_wrapper">Bar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is your answer, 10minites after mine, adding more value?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan didn't notice yours till I posted mine